# Did Facebook just change their layout for canvas apps with Fixed width (760px)?

Tags: facebook, user-interface, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I noticed that yesterday all the **Fixed-width canvas apps** started looking strange: the Facebook chrome is pushed away from the canvas and takes up all the browser page's width, as it does for **Fluid-width apps** (see [Farmville](http://apps.facebook.com/onthefarm/) for example).

Is this a permanent behavior, or a bug?

If it's not a bug, is it documented anywhere? I could not find any info on that on Facebook's developer documentation.

(Most fixed width apps look kind of strange right now)

Cheers,

Julien

Comment: I just noticed this as well, and had the same question if it was intentional or not.  I can confirm that they are still restricting it to 760px width at least.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This was indeed a permanent behavior, though not documented beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook have added fluid width to all canvas applications.

**You can find it if you go to:**

1. https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Edit Settings
3. Settings -> Advanced
4. Canvas Settings -> Canvas Width (*Fixed sets the canvas page width to 760 pixels. Fluid left aligns the canvas page and sets the width dynamically to fill the page.*)

**Interesting links:**

- [Blogpost from Facebook devs on the subject.](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/)
- [Showcase of games that use fluid width](https://developers.facebook.com/showcase/games/)